# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'genfromtxt'

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I tried running the following program

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter = ',')
```

which gives

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'genfromtxt'

Help much appreciated

Comment: what verion of numpy?

Comment: What does `np.__file__` say?

Comment: The one that came with Anaconda 2.1.0 And I am using Python 2.7.8

Comment: Are you sure?  This method exists for me in 1.4.1 but not in 1.0.4.  What does `np.__version__` contain?

Answer (score 0):

You must import matplotlib and it will work
copy and past next code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter = ',')
```

Comment: Why would this work? Importing matplotlib shouldn't affect numpy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).